# How does forward declaration save compile time?

Tags: c++, gcc, compilation, clang, forward-declaration

If you read online then there is plenty of claims that in C++ if you use forward declaration then it saves your compile time. The usual theory is that since `#include` means mere text replacement if I use forward declaration, then my compiler doesn't need to parse the header and possibly compile it, so it saves time. I found this claim hard to believe because consider I usually see code like this:

```
// B.h

class A;

class B {
public:
void doSomething(A& a);
}
```

In this case, yeah, we don't need to include  `A.h` in `B.h` as we forward declared it, but the problem is that in `B.cpp` eventually, we need a full type `A` to use its methods and data members. So I found in nearly all cases, we need to include `A.h` in `B.cpp`.

So how does forward declaration actually save compile time? I see people with benchmarks to prove that if they use forward declaration instead of `#include`s, the compile time actually goes down, so there must be something I do not understand here...

---

I know saving compile time is not the sole purpose of forward declaration, I understand it has other purposes. I just want to understand why some people claim it can save compile time.

Comment: Forward declaration isn't about "saving compiler time", it's about declaring symbols so they can be used before their definition.

Comment: forward declaration allow you to break circular dependencies.  If `A` needs `B`, and `B` needs `A`, there is no way to do that without forward declarations.

Comment: It can save time if there's a translation unit that doesn't actually need the type defined. For example maybe there's a translation unit that never uses `B::doSomething`, but needs to include `B.h` for something else. But that's not really the purpose of a forward declaration anyway.

Comment: There is a book that has several chapters on this subject, **Large-scale C++ Software Design** by John Lakos.  Basically, don't `#include` what you don't use, do `#include` what you use, and headers should try hard to limit the number of headers they depend upon.  For the problem presented, I'd have the forward declaration in a "A.hh" header-header file, and include that in B.h, and in B.cpp it would have `#include "A.h"`.

Comment: Forward declaration will only save compile time if using the declarations allow you to avoid reading or rebuilding a file. In this case if A.h is changed, you don't have to rebuild the files that include B.h but not A.h. Depending on what is in b.h and how the project is laid out this could be many files or it could be few files. As always, profile.

Comment: Also, even for projects with tens of [translation units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) and several thousands of lines of code and complex templates, you rarely have to worry about "compilation time" these days with modern multi-GHz processors and SSD's. Like any optimization, for normal projects don't bother about it until it becomes an issue (or you have very specific and explicit requirements).

Comment: In simplest terms, forward declarations lead to less code in a compilation unit.  Code takes time to compile, so less code means less time spent compiling code.

Comment: "Some people claim it can save compile time" It's rather simple to explain: The less header files that needs to be included in a translation unit, the less code there will be to parse and compile, and the less time it will take.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude that's where I don't understand, in my example you still need to include "A.h". But as some other points out in this thread there will be other translation units where they include "B.h" and not including "A.h", and that will help.

Comment: My attention span is shot these days. Ten seconds of compiling has become an intolerable disruption.

Comment: With the code as currently shown, there's no need for the full definition of `A`. But in the source file for `B` where `doSomething` is defined (implemented) you of course need the full definition of `A` and its header file. *But* even with header include guards or `#pragma once` the compiler still needs to open the file and start parsing it to figure out that it has already been included. So instead of opening the `A.h` file (at least) twice, it's only opened *once*. Saves some very little time.

Comment: Well I work with a code base where it needs at least 10 minutes to compile on a high end machine (120GB memory) so it do matter to try everything I can to make it compile faster...

Comment: [Continued] Now extrapolate it over tens or maybe even hundreds of header files. Then it starts to become measurable.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: In my experience, requirements tend to expand to use available resources. My current project at work has a couple thousand translation units (and if you count external libraries that get built once in a while, more like ten thousand). That's not a particularly large project either.

Comment: If you always need full definitions of A when including B, you gain nothing from the forward declaration, and I start to wonder if they are tightly coupled enough that they should both be in the same header. I'll make a count of the number of files that require A without requiring B, ponder the conceptual benefits of describing each in separate headers, and make a call.

Comment: Once worked for a company that insisted of full rebuilds of everything, including the libraries, on every build. Quit after a few months. Four hour build to test one bug fix gave me much time to read novels, but very little job satisfaction. Got pretty  good at making what we call [mre]s around here, though.

Comment: @JerryCoffin I once worked at a place which built a custom Linux distribution, from source. Since the build-system was kind of fragile and dependencies could become broken quite easily, most people usually rebuilt the whole thing from scratch every Monday morning. Good time to start that and then have the standup and a few other meetings before it was finished. :)

Comment: One other benefit - information hiding.  Say the `DoSomething()` method above was private.  Do client .cpp files of class B that include B.h need to even KNOW about ANY details about A?  Implementation file(s) of class B need to know (and would include a.h), but do the client .cpp files of class B need to know?  This could be a couple files - or a thousand.

Comment: One more - is A.h in the include path of client .cpp files of B.h?  A.h may be buried somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Compile times

> the problem is that in `B.cpp` eventually, we need a full type `A` to use its methods and data members.

Yes, that is a typical pattern. Forward declare a class (e.g. `A`) in a header (e.g. `B.h`), then in the source code corresponding to that header (`B.cpp`), include the header for the forward-declared class (`A.h`).

> So I found in nearly all cases, we need to include `B.h` in `B.cpp`.

Correct, forward declarations do not save time *when compiling the corresponding source code*. The savings come when compiling other source code that uses `B`. For example:

**other.cpp**

```cpp
#include "B.h"

// Do stuff with `B` objects.
// Make no use of `A` objects.
```

Assume this file does not need definitions from `A.h`. This is where the savings come in. When compiling `other.cpp`, if `B.h` uses a forward declaration of `A`, there is no need to process `A.h`. Nor is there a need to process the headers that `A.h` itself includes, and so on. Now multiply this effect by the number of files that include `B.h`, either directly or indirectly.

Note that there is a compounding effect here. The number of "headers that `A.h` itself includes" and of "files that include `B.h`" would be the numbers before replacing any `#include` statements with forward declarations. (Once you start making these replacements, the numbers come down.)

How much of an effect? Not as much as there used to be. Still, as long as we're talking theoretically, even the smallest savings is still a savings.

## Rebuild times

Instead of raw compile times (build everything), I think a better focus would be on rebuild times. That is, the time it takes to compile just the files affected by a change you made.

Suppose there are ten files that rely on `B.h` but not on `A.h`. If `B.h` were to include `A.h`, then those ten files would be affected by changes to `A.h`. If `B.h` were instead to forward declare `A`, then those files would not be affected by changes to `A.h`, reducing the time to rebuild after those changes.

Now suppose there is another class, call it `B2`, that also has the option to forward declare `A` instead of including the header. Maybe there are another ten files that depend on `B2` but not on `B` and not on `A`. Now there are a twenty files that do not need to be re-compiled after changes to `A`.

But why stop there? Let's add `B3` through `B10` to the mix. Now there are a hundred files that do not need to be re-compiled after changes to `A`.

Add another layer. Suppose there is a `C.h` that has the option to forward declare `B` instead of including `B.h`. By using a forward declarations, changes to `A.h` no longer require re-compiling the ten files that use `C.h`. And, of course, we'll assume there are ten such files for each of `B` through `B10`. Now we're up to `10*10*10` files that do not need to be recompiled when `A.h` changes.

### Takeaway

This is a simplified example to serve as a demonstration. The point is that there is a forest of dependency trees created by `#include` lines. (The root of such a tree would be the header file of interest, and its children are the files that `#include` it.) Each leaf in one of these trees represents a file that must be compiled when changes occur in the header file of interest. The number of leaves in a tree grows exponentially with the depth, so removing a branch (by replacing an `#include` with a forward declaration) can have a massive effect on rebuild time. Or maybe a negligible effect. This is theory, not practice.

---

I should note that like the question, this answer focuses on compile times, not on the other factors to consider. This is not supposed to be a comprehensive guide to the pros and cons of forward declarations, just an explanation for how they could save compilation time.